# How do you delete an Azure Web Job?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I want to remove my Azure Web job.  How can I do this from the new portal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to the snapshot below:
[image]

Comment: Wow, unintuitive, had no idea there were right click commands available since almost all of the functions on the site are through icons and links.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- in the new portal, go to the WebJobs list
- right click on a WebJob, and you'll see the option to delete it

Comment: It's definitely there. See @forester123's answer which includes screenshot.